# Cut and paste data values in blank cell in the column

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing an Excel VBA Project. I have got data in an excel file as follows

```
aa bb
aa bb
aa bb
aa bb
aa bb
```

I would like to copy all of the `bb` values to the blank cell below the `aa` values, so that it appears as such.

```
aa
aa
aa
aa
aa
bb
bb
bb
bb
bb
```

Is there a VBA code to help me out, if my `aa` values are of variable length and my blank cell in the `aa` column is not a definite cell?

Thanks!

Comment: So record and playback didn't helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code (I suppose that your `bb` values starts from `B1` cell, but you could easily change it):

```
Sub test()
   Dim lastrowA As Long, lastrowB As Long
   'determining last row of aa values'
   lastrowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   'determining last row of bb values'
   lastrowB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'cut and paste (suppose that your bb values starts from B1)'
   Range("B1:B" & lastrowB).Cut Range("A" & lastrowA + 1)

End Sub
```